# ESP32 BLE Client only reads 8 characters from characteristic

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, arduino-esp32

The Arduino ESP32 BLE_Client example returns only 8 characters when reading the BLE sensor's characteristic, i.e. 3ffe50a8, instead of the expected 16 characters (0x6701340022001F00) that I see when using the nRF Connect app.

I have tried changing the data type for pData from uint8_t* to uint16_t* in the notifyCallback call, and also in BLERemoteCharacteristic::registerForNotify, however this just caused more issues down the line.

Does anyone have an idea how to get the read and return the full value 16 character value from the characteristic?

Answer (score 0):

You have to increase the MTU size to 512